# Table column isn't populating, is it controller or join table issue?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot

Have a `Java/Springboot/Thymeleaf/Hibernate/SQL` application that allows admins to post new articles. Each article is associated with specific topics. In `SQL` I have a `topic table`, an `articles table` and a `join table` that holds the `articleIds` and `topicsIds`.

When I add a new article through the app, the `"Topic"` column in the article table is supposed to populate with whichever topic name is chosen from a drop down field, you can select more than one topic, so ideally the column needs to collect all selected topic names.

Do you think this is an issue with my `sql` table or do I need to be setting the selected topics some how, in my controller? I've tried setting it in the controller, but not sure I am grabbing it correctly since there can be multiple `"topic"` chosen from the topics... any ideas?

Here is my code for the Article model.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Article")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Article {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ArticleId")
    private Long id;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a")
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    private String title;
    private String urlTitle;
    private String contentHtml;
    private String contentText;
    private String topic;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
            })
    @JoinTable(name = "Article_Topics",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Article") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Topic") })
    private Set<Topic> topics= new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getUrlTitle() {
        return urlTitle;
    }

    public void setUrlTitle(String urlTitle) {
        this.urlTitle = urlTitle;
    }

    public String getContentHtml() {
        return contentHtml;
    }

    public void setContentHtml(String contentHtml) {
        this.contentHtml = contentHtml;
    }

    public String getContentText() {
        return contentText;
    }

    public void setContentText(String contentText) {
        this.contentText = contentText;
    }

    public Set<Topic> getTopics() {
        return topics;
    }

    public void setTopics(Set<Topic> topics) {
        this.topics = topics;
    }

    public String getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }

    public void setTopic(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the controller, when you save a new topic:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save-article")
    public String addArticle(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value="article")Article newArticle, @ModelAttribute(value="topics")Article topics){
        String newArticleName = newArticle.getTitle().replaceAll("\\s","");
        newArticle.setUrlTitle(newArticleName);

        articleRepository.save(newArticle);
        return adminHome(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a topic column inside the Article table. As per your explanation, you have a "ManyToMany" scenario where one article can have many topics and one topic can be associated with many articles.

To fulfil this requirement you have already created a join table, then I don't understand why you have created the topic column again in Article table. To explain it simply, you cannot have multiple data in one field. So if one article has 3 topics, how can you put all 3 in the same column.

I recommend you to go through [this](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many) link to get a proper understanding of Many to Many cases and how to handle them in hibernate.